# Inheriting from Generic and NamedTuple fails with "missing required positional argument"

Tags: python, generics, python-typing, namedtuple

I've encountered a problem when trying to define a generic (typing/mypy `Generic`) `NamedTuple`. I've managed to reduce it to smallest possible working example:

a.py:

```
from typing import NamedTuple
from typing import Generic
from typing import TypeVar

T = TypeVar('T')

class A(Generic[T], NamedTuple('A', [('x', T)])):
    pass

a = A(12)
```

This is completely fine on all python version we (have to) support (including 3.4, 3.7), except 3.5.3, where it fails:

```
$ python3 a.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "a.py", line 10, in <module>
    a = A(12)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/typing.py", line 1126, in __new__
    return _generic_new(cls.__next_in_mro__, cls, *args, **kwds)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/typing.py", line 1087, in _generic_new
    return base_cls.__new__(cls)
TypeError: __new__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'x'
```

I tried to manually add `__new__` method:

```
class A(Generic[T], NamedTuple('A', [('x', T)])):
    def __new__(cls, a):
        return super(A, cls).__new__(cls, a)
```

but it fails with exactly the same error message.

Explicitly naming parameter `x` (`a = A(x=12)`) gives the same error message too.

Is there a way to make it work?

**Please, don't tell me to upgrade python, we support multiple python versions and 3.5.3 is one of them. Upgrading python is not an option here.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the answer is pretty simple - I just reversed order of `Generic` and `NamedTuple` and it works in all python versions we support:

```
class A(NamedTuple('A', [('x', T)]), Generic[T]):
    pass
```